# using Request.GetBufferlessInputStream() correctly for POST data c#

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have created a c# web page which will be listening for POST data from a service. I've seen that I may need to use Request.GetBufferlessInputStream() which will read in the page data. I will then process this data further in my code.

However, I cannot get the post data! I have found that I need to use

```
Stream httpStream = Request.GetBufferlessInputStream();
Response.Write(httpStream.ToString());
```

but I am not sure how to then read that. I have tried reading from 0 to the end, but get only numbers returned (assume byte data?).

I basically want to see a string! I've been using CURL to fake a post. That code is here

```
curl -H "Content Type: application/xml" -d "<callback var=\"matt\">" -X POST http://localhost:1111/Default.aspx
```

So I would expect my script to output `<callback var="matt">`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need-

```
Stream stream = Request.InputStream;

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Request.ContentEncoding);

string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(), Request.ContentEncoding))
{
    string requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

This reads using the non-blocking async method and the `using` statement properly disposes the stream.