# extract variables and values from http post / string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I am trying to read in POST data to an ASPX (c#) page. I have got the post data now inside a string. I am now wondering if this is the best way to use it. Using the code here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386534/using-request-getbufferlessinputstream-correctly-for-post-data-c-sharp) I have the following string

```
<callback variable1="foo1" variable2="foo2" variable3="foo3" />
```

As this is now in a string, I am splitting based on a space.

```
    string[] pairs = theResponse.Split(' ');
    Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string pair in pairs)
    {
        string[] paramvalue = pair.Split('=');
        results.Add(paramvalue[0], paramvalue[1]);
        Debug.WriteLine(paramvalue[0].ToString());
    }
```

The trouble comes when a value has a space in it. For example, `variable3="foo 3"` upsets the code.

Is there something better I should be doing to parse the incoming http post variables within the  string??

Comment: You can use RegEx to parse your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to treat it as XML directly:

```
// just use 'theResponse' here instead
var xml = "<callback variable1=\"foo1\" variable2=\"foo2\" variable3=\"foo3\" />";

// once inside an XElement you can get all the values
var ele = XElement.Parse(xml);

// an example of getting the attributes out
var values = ele.Attributes().Select(att => new { Name = att.Name, Value = att.Value });

// or print them
foreach (var attr in ele.Attributes())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
}
```

Of course you can change that last line to whatever you want, the above is a rough example.

Comment: that's great- thanks! I can see the name -> value in the debug window. I am confused as to how I'd populate my variables though. (using the 'var values = ele...' line). Can I specify to populate string var1 = ele.Attributes().Select() to get just the value of "variable1" ?